# AngularJS issue with routeProvider and hashtag in url

Tags: angularjs, routes, hashtag

I've some problem with my angular app, running on virtual host. 
I'm use wamp with vhost settings: **DocumentRoot "c:/sites/test.dev/www"**.

Have problem with **ROUTES**. I want, that my app page open like this:
**http://test.dev/1** , where **1** = user_id.

This is my app.js:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
        controller: 'UserController',
    });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

When i disable **$locationProvider**, all works fine, but hashtag "#" always appended to url, like  **http://test.dev/#/1** . Can anyone have some idea?

App folder **/www/** with structure:

- /controller/
- /services/
- /directives/
- /views/
- ---/js/
- ---/css/
- ---user.html
- app.js
- index.html

Comment: "When i disable $locationProvider, all works fine" - does it work when you enable $locationProvider ?

Comment: No( routeProvider does't work

Comment: Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://custom.dev/1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: Meaning: $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); - doesn't work, $locationProvider.html5Mode(false); - works with "#" problem?

Comment: try binding to something like: .when('/myprefix/:id'

Comment: Mean than $locationProvider doesn't work anyway. I always must write http://custom.dev/#/1, then he replace my url to http://custom.dev/1, but when try to write http://custom.dev/1 - erorr 404

Comment: you testing on on ie8?

Comment: IE8? I dont have this browser

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following code:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
   enabled: true,
   requireBase: false
});
```

It will work for you.